# Defining elapsed months for every row in a data.table in R

Tags: r, date, data.table, date-difference

I have a data.table like the following

```
    ID   Date_col    Value
    1    2017-08-01  A
    1    2017-09-01  A
    1    2017-10-01  B
    2    2017-06-01  A
    2    2017-07-01  A        
    2    2017-08-01  C        
    2    2017-09-01  A
```

And I would like to add a column, indicating the spent months from the first observation by ID, like this:

```
    ID   Date_col    Value  Months_spent  
    1    2017-08-01  A      0
    1    2017-09-01  A      1
    1    2017-10-01  B      2
    2    2017-06-01  A      0
    2    2017-07-01  A      1 
    2    2017-08-01  C      2 
    2    2017-09-01  A      3
```

I tried this, but I get an error, that the "to" date must be of lenght 1

```
DT[, Months_spent := length(seq.Date(Date_col[1L], Date_col, by = "month")), by = ID]
```

Please help me with this error, but of course, any other effective solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option in data.table:

```
dt[, Months_spent := {
  full_seq <- seq.Date(Date_col[1L], max(Date_col), by = "month")
  match(Date_col, full_seq) - 1L
}, by = ID]
#    ID   Date_col Value Months_spent
# 1:  1 2017-08-01     A            0
# 2:  1 2017-09-01     A            1
# 3:  1 2017-10-01     B            2
# 4:  2 2017-06-01     A            0
# 5:  2 2017-07-01     A            1
# 6:  2 2017-08-01     C            2
# 7:  2 2017-09-01     A            3
```

This assumes that the initial data is already orderd, i.e. each ID starts with its earliest month and is a correct Date/IDate format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution which works also with unordered dates, gaps in the monthly sequence of dates and also with dates within a month, e.g., `2017-08-15`:

```
as.IMonth <- function(x) 12 * year(x) + month(x)
DT2[, Months_spent := as.IMonth(Date_col) - as.IMonth(min(Date_col)), by = ID][]

   ID   Date_col Value Months_spent
1:  1 2017-08-01     A            0
2:  1 2017-09-01     A            1
3:  1 2017-10-01     B            2
4:  1 2018-02-01     X            6
5:  2 2017-06-01     A            0
6:  2 2017-07-01     A            1
7:  2 2017-08-01     C            2
8:  2 2017-08-15     X            2
9:  2 2017-09-01     A            3
```

Note that rows with `Value == X` have been added to OP's sample dataset to demonstrate gaps and intra-month dates.

#### Data

```
DT <- fread(
  "    ID   Date_col    Value
  1    2017-08-01  A
  1    2017-09-01  A
  1    2017-10-01  B
  2    2017-06-01  A
  2    2017-07-01  A        
  2    2017-08-01  C        
  2    2017-09-01  A  ")[, Date_col := as.IDate(Date_col)][]

DT2 <- rbind(DT, 
             fread("ID Date_col Value\n1 2018-02-01 X\n2 2017-08-15 X")[
               , Date_col := as.IDate(Date_col)])
setorder(DT2, ID, Date_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(months_spent = month(Date_col) - first(month(Date_col)))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups: ID [2]
#     ID   Date_col Value months_spent
#  <int>     <date> <chr>        <int>
#1     1 2017-08-01     A            0
#2     1 2017-09-01     A            1
#3     1 2017-10-01     B            2
#4     2 2017-06-01     A            0
#5     2 2017-07-01     A            1
#6     2 2017-08-01     C            2
#7     2 2017-09-01     A            3
```

---

Or if there are multiple `year`s

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(months_spent =  as.integer(round((Date_col - first(Date_col))/(365/12))))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups: ID [2]
#     ID   Date_col Value months_spent
#  <int>     <date> <chr>        <int>
#1     1 2017-08-01     A            0
#2     1 2017-09-01     A            1
#3     1 2017-10-01     B            2
#4     2 2017-06-01     A            0
#5     2 2017-07-01     A            1
#6     2 2017-08-01     C            2
#7     2 2017-09-01     A            3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reliable solution using dplyr and zoo. It will group by each ID and always get the difference of months based on the first Date_col value for that ID.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Date_col = c("8/1/2017","9/1/2017","10/1/2017","6/1/2017","7/1/2017","8/1/2017","9/1/2017"),
                 Value = c("A","A","B","A","A","C","A"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df$Date_col <- as.Date(df$Date_col, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

df <- df %>%
      arrange(ID, Date_col) %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(Months_spent = 12 * as.numeric(as.yearmon(Date_col, "%Y %b") - as.yearmon(first(Date_col), "%Y %b")))

#> df
#Source: local data frame [7 x 5]
#Groups: ID [2]
#
#     ID   Date_col Value       lead Months_spent
#  <dbl>     <date> <chr>     <date>        <dbl>
#1     1 2017-08-01     A 2017-08-01            0
#2     1 2017-09-01     A 2017-09-01            1
#3     1 2017-10-01     B 2017-10-01            2
#4     2 2017-06-01     A 2017-06-01            0
#5     2 2017-07-01     A 2017-07-01            1
#6     2 2017-08-01     C 2017-08-01            2
#7     2 2017-09-01     A 2017-09-01            3
```